# Pandas: how to use groupby, sum and multiply at the same time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame as follows:

```
shop | item_price  | item_sold
A    |    123      |     1
B    |    921      |     2
A    |     28      |     4
...
```

I want to find the total revenue by each shop. In SQL it looks like this:

```sql
SELECT shop, SUM((item_price * item_sold)) as revenue
FROM table
GROUP BY shop
```

I want to do it in Python using Pandas. I tried:

```py
revenue_by_shop = table.groupby("shop")[table["item_price"] * table["item_sold"]].sum()
```

But that does not seem like the right answer.

Comment: In Pandas, you need to calculate the revenue first, then sum it, so something like this should work : ``df.assign(revenue=df.item_price * df.item_sold).groupby("shop").revenue.sum()``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can multiple values to `Series` and pass to groupby Series `table["shop"]`:

```
df = ((table["item_price"] * table["item_sold"])
              .groupby(table["shop"])
              .sum()
              .reset_index(name='revenue'))
```

Or create new column by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and pass colum name `shop` to `groupby`:

```
df = (table.assign(revenue = table["item_price"] * table["item_sold"])
           .groupby("shop", as_index=False)['revenue']
           .sum())
```

Answer (score 3):

I will do it in this way to not overcomplicate it.

```
df['revenue'] = df['item_price'] * df['item_sold']
revenue_by_shop = df.groupby("shop")['revenue'].sum()
```